# React doesn't work if I pre-compile JSX with Babel command-line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, babeljs

In my `ui.js`, I have:

```
const root = const root = document.getElementById('root');

function updateUI(data) {
    var renderData = data.map((i) =>
        <DataItem id={i[0]} value={i[1]} />
    );
    ReactDOM.render(renderData, root);
}
```

This works perfectly fine when I use in-browser Babel transformer. However, after running `npx babel ui.js -o ui-transpiled.js`, this is what it looks like:

```
const root = document.getElementById('root');

function updateUI(data) {
    var renderData = data.map(i => React.createElement(DataItem, { id: i[0], value: i[1] }));
    ReactDOM.render(renderData, root);
}
```

This doesn't work - Chrome console says: react-dom.production.min.js:12 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Minified React error #200

However, if I swap out `ReactDOM.render(renderData, root);` to `ReactDOM.render(renderData, document.getElementById('root'));`, it works. For some reason, the constant `root` defined at the top of the document is producing a "Target container is not a DOM element." error, but not when I'm using in-browser Babel.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where are you embedding the script tag? If the script tag is before the body (or specifically the 'root' element), you're constant is going to be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (thanks kalley)!

Basically, my script was being loaded in the head, and thus `const root` was null because the body hasn't loaded yet.